# Vite cannot resolve diff-match-patch in prod build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to switch from `VueCLI` to `Vite`. Everything works fine in dev mode in Vite however when I try to build prod I am getting this error.

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "diff-match-patch" from "src/components/Viewer.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "diff-match-patch" from "src/components/DiffViewer.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
```

I cannot externalize this library since my application needs it. Here is how I am importing the library

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { DIFF_DELETE, DIFF_EQUAL, DIFF_INSERT, diff_match_patch as DiffMatchPatch } from 'diff-match-patch'
```

This is working fine in `VueCLI` both in Dev and Prod build but not in `Vite` (prod mode) is there anyway to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout whether "diff-match-patch" is in package.json.

I tried with your code and get the same error when "diff-match-patch" are not installed.

Comment: Now I feel silly. Somehow I forgot to copy paste that library but I copy/pasted the types. Thank you very much for your help.